# C# : How to implement GetHashCode for below type of class?

Tags: c#

I have a class similar to below:

```
class Abc
{
     public string A {get;set;}
     public string B {get;set;}
}
```

The criteria for equals is if any of `A` or `B` matches two objects of class `Abc` should match.

```
public override bool Equals (Abc obj)
{
      if (obj.A == A || obj.B == B)
           return true;
      else return false;
}
```

Can anyone let me know what kind of `GetHashCode` function would give equal values in such cases.

Because both `A` & `B` fields may or may not have same values.

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure if i understand your question: Do you want to compare string A with string B of class Abc? Or do you want to match i.e. two instances of Abc to either have an equal A or B?

Comment: Could be really useful to check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden

Comment: I doubt there is a way to produce a GetHashCode that seems logical in this case.

Comment: Aside: You have a bug in your `Equals` method - it must be `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError No, that is the exact thing that makes this illogical. He actually wants the `||`.

Comment: But he is breaking transitivity rules here, which makes this whole situation pretty bad. I see there is an answer here that mentions this now.

Comment: Well, IMHO, attempting to redefine the semantics of `Equals` will cause nothing but headaches.

Comment: My question here is { A=John B =Smith} and {A=John B=Doe} this both objects are equal in my coding scenario. Hence I needed similar hashcode function implemented. If any one of the field matches, its a match for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one and only must-have requirement for implementing `GetHashCode` is that when two objects are considered equal (i.e. `Equals` returns true), then their hash codes must match.

In your case, if you have two different objects with x = (A1, B1) and y = (A2, B2), then their hash code must be the same because it must be the same as z = (A1, B2), because x and z are considered equal and so are y and z. Therefore, the only valid implementation of `GetHashCode` is to always return a constant number, for example 0.

You might wonder because a `GetHashCode` implementation that simply returns a constant number makes no sense and that is true; the reason is that your `Equals` also does not make sense. Your biggest problem is that `Equals` is not transitive. x and z are equal and z and y are, but x and y are not. This is contrary to what you would expect.